# Rails not redirecting to an external URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want a simple functionality of redirecting to an external site from controller. I am using this code.

```
redirect_to "https://www.google.com", allow_other_host: true
```

And from the logs I get

```
Redirected to https://www.google.com
Completed 302 Found in 2927ms (Allocations: 15729)
```

But I am actually not redirected and browser shows CORS error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There must be something playing in there. The redirect should redirect you. Are you sure you don't ping your controller with an async request or such ?

Comment: Just tested on mine, it works fine. I am redirect to Google. Test on different browser and see if you get same error.

Comment: can you try this once and check `redirect_to "https://www.google.com",:status => 302`